# Function operator and function declaration used as an onclick handler behave differently

Tags: javascript, scope

I have two functions:

```
doSomething = function()  {
    alert(this);
}


var doSomethingElse = function() {
    alert(this);
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id='button1' onclick='doSomething()'>Do Something</button>
  <button id='button2' onclick='doSomethingElse()'>Do Something Else</button>
</div>
```

Why does `doSomething()` function call work while `doSomethingElse()` does not?

https://jsfiddle.net/brjdp56t/

Comment: It can work in my side

Comment: @lucumt - You're probably using the code at global scope. The OP's fiddle doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference. This creates `doSomething` in the global scope:

```
doSomething = function()
```

This creates `doSomething` in the current scope:

```
var doSomething = function()
```

The reason why the latter does not work is because you are executing this code inside a scope (closure, `window.onload = function() {}`, `$(function() {})` etc) and the variable is therefore unavailable outside the scope. In the fiddle, the JavaScript code is wrapped inside `window.onload = function() { var doSomethingElse = ... }`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. So this is basically due to how JSFiddle works?

Comment: @ashwnacharya Yes. But you can change fiddle options. Click on the JavaScript heading inside JavaScript tab and change the `LOAD TYPE` option. It defaults to `On Load`, change to `no wrap - bottom of <body>` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does doSomething() function call work while doSomethingElse() does not?

That will only be true if the code you've shown *isn't* at global scope (the code in your fiddle is wrapped in an `onload` handler provided by jsFiddle itself, see the options on the JavaScript pane — this is one of jsFiddle's more <s>ridiculous</s>*surprising* default options). The reason is what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). By not declaring `doSomething` in this code:

```
doSomething = function()  {
        alert(this);
}
```

...you're creating a *global* variable called `doSomething`. But by declaring `doSomethingElse` in this code:

```
var doSomethingElse = function() {
    alert(this);
}
```

...you're creating a *local* variable in the scope where that code exists.

Why does it matter? Because any function you call in an old `onXYZ`-attribute-style event handler has to be a global.

Instead:

1. Use strict mode (`"use strict"`) so that assigning to an undeclared identifier is an error instead of creating an automatic global.
2. Use modern event handling (`addEventListener` and such) rather than `onXYZ`-attribute-style event handlers that require global functions.
3. Put your `script` tag at the end of the document body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so that all elements defined by your HTML have been created before the code runs. (Then you don't need `onload` or similar handlers.)

For example (Stack Snippets put the automatic `script` tag at the end of `body` for you):

```js
"use strict";
// Scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
    var doSomething = function()  {
        console.log("doSomething");
    };

    var doSomethingElse = function() {
        console.log("doSomethingElse");
    };
    
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
    document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", doSomethingElse);
})();
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id='button1'>Do Something</button>
  <button id='button2'>Do Something Else</button>
</div>
```